# Least possible degree of polynomial with atleast one irrational root

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ..... + a_nx^n$ be a nonzero polynomial with integer coefficients. If $p(\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 6) = 0$, then the smallest possible value of $n$ is?

Answer (score 2):

The stabilizer of $ \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6} $ is trivial in the Galois group of $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\mathbb Q $, so its minimal polynomial is of degree 4 over $ \mathbb{Q} $. Therefore, $ n = 4 $.

To compute the polynomial, define $ \alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6} $ and note that the map $ T(x) = \alpha x $ defined on $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q} $ has the following matrix form wrt the natural basis:

$$ T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\ 1 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $ x^4 - 22x^2 - 48x - 23 $. Since any linear operator is killed by its characteristic polynomial, we conclude that this polynomial has $ \alpha $ as a root. Since $ \alpha $ was of degree 4 over $ \mathbb{Q} $, this is its minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6$$
$$x-\sqrt6=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$$
$$\left(x-\sqrt6\right)^2=\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt3\right)^2$$

Comment: And then group $\sqrt{6}$ on the RHS and square again.

Comment: This allows you to find a polynomial $ P \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $ such that $ P(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}) = 0 $, but it doesn't show that this polynomial is of smallest possible degree.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 6$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 6)$ and $\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt3=\sqrt6$ so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 6)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3)$ It is easy now to find the degree four of the required polynomial.

Comment: How do you know that your first assertion is true? (The one about the number being a primitive element)

Comment: By definition: the simplest p. e. is $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$ but also are $a\sqrt 2+b\sqrt 3$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary non zero rational. And so is $a\sqrt 2+b\sqrt 3+c\sqrt 6$ because $\sqrt 6$ is a rational function of $\sqrt 2$ and  $\sqrt 3$ (the function $f(x,y)=xy$). All this is in relation with the respective Galois group.